# How to remove ScanSoft SSBkgdUpdate.exe for good?

Tags: windows-7, scanner, bloatware

On Windows 7, `SSBkgdUpdate.exe` pops up every time a non-admin user logs in, asking for the admin password. This is the auto-updater for ScanSoft PaperPort 11.

I tried to zap it by deleting the executable. But it magically reappeared after reboot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling or just disable it's autostart?

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Sysinternals is a good tool for managing startup issues. Use something like [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) (free) if you want to uninstall it (as the web-wisdom says it leaves cruft behind)

Comment: Autoruns is the tool for this job, you'll need to find the other process(es) that are restoring the program. Check for system services as well, because this would require elevated privileges to keep re-creating itself.

Comment: Autoruns did it!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Download [Start-up Manager](http://startupmanager.org/)

**2)** After installing Start-up manager, in the left panel "Start sections" Click on "All users."

**3)** Now in the right panel, look for SSBkgdUpdate.exe, once you find it un-check it.

This will remove SSBkgdUpdate.exe in other accounts , make sure you do this from the administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

SSBkgdupdate.exe

I've got the above "Shield with Yellow & Blue 'virus' / dodgy programme" that comes up on start up every time I switch on.  I have tried to get rid of it and failed — I've had it for two months.

I looked up `SSBkgdupdate.exe` on the 'net. It seems that it is a common problem, with several websites saying it is bad (they would say that, wouldn't they!) and linking to "how to get rid of SSBkgdupdate.exe," but I couldn’t get them to work or they themselves looked suspect.

THE SOLUTION FOR ME:
I've managed to get rid of `SSBkgdupdate.exe` at last. After going to my C drive, I managed to find "common files," went into that and amazingly I found "SSBkgdupdate" sitting there all innocently.

Its properties showed

```
Type      File folder
Origin    Scansoft shared
Size      152 mb
Created   27 Sept 12 17.51
```

So I just pressed delete and it has gone and no longer appears on my startup screen!

Answer (score 1):

At my installation this popup had been caused by an installation of OmniPage. I could disable the popup by the already mentioned method with msconfig:
Start -> msconfig.exe -> Startup -> there I unchecked "SSEreg" and "Nuance Omnipage...".
Omnipage will work nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Just click *Start*. At the bottom type `msconfig` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Click the tab *Startup*. Scroll down and uncheck `SSBkgdUpdater`.

Warning: Unchecking things will effect the operation of your computer. Most third party can be unchecked.  It will then ask you to restart.